# Switch to custom views in Agenda via org-agenda-view-mode-dispatch

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

Is ist possible to add custom views to agenda which can be accessed via org-agenda-view-mode-dispatch?

Its very convenient to press just "v" and "l" to make agenda show completed tasks. It would be great to be able to filter the current view for special `TODO` keywords or tags the same way. Like pressing "v" and "n" to only show todos with `NEXT` keyword in the current agenda view.

I am fairly new to emacs.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible out of the box. `org-agenda-view-mode-dispatch` is just a big case statement: if the user presses *this* key, then call *that* function. The set of keys that it recognizes and the set of functions that it calls is fixed beforehand.

That does not prevent you from rewriting the function in a more extensible way (and if you do, you might want to propose it for inclusion to Org mode: send mail to the Org mode mailing list).